# Can we programatically change font of multiple UILabels at once(by minimal lines of code)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I am a newbie in iOS programming. Here is the situation I am facing: I have to programmatically create a view with some 25 labels in it. Of all the 25 labels, some features like color and font-size etc are common.

The obvious solution is to handle every label individually. But I am curious to know Is there a way to assign a common font to all of them by writing minimal coding or am I left with alternative of separately handling each label..

I have researched the solution on net but with no success. If there is an alternative , It can help in future if someone handles a large no. of subviews. 
Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I don't the the point to mark it as not a real question. @trojanfoe your comment is not really constructive... It is obvious what na19 means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can sqeeze it all into one cramped line:

```
[view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ [([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(setFont:)] ? obj : nil) setFont:newFont];}];
```

Comment: want to try it coz looking Great..@ +1

Comment: @trojanfoe I disagree. It's obfuscated and ugly.

Comment: But powerful and meets the requirements.

Comment: @trojanfoe Also, I'm cheating regarding the one-line requirement. I would normally write the block on three lines. Yet, I can't downvote my own post.

Comment: Of course, but you could write an entire program in "one line", but nobody would.  I still like it.

Comment: The OP wanted to affect UILabels; this currently affects any setFont-responding view.

Comment: @magma You can easily change the code to use `isKindOfClass:` instead. I usually prefer `respondsToSelector:` because it's way faster. Performance is not an issue here, though, and I agree that my code does not match the official requirements.

Answer (score 1):

try this .

```
for( UIView *subVeiw in self.subviews)  {
   if([subVeiw isKindOfClass:[UILabel Class]])   {
     [(UILabel *)subVeiw setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:20]];
     //You can set the Font like this.

     //Here is Your UILabel Object if you want to use it.
     UILabel *yourLabel  =  (UILabel *) subVeiw;
   }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to (for some reason) use a single line of code.

Comment: @trojanfoe here is nothing that tried before the Question that's why i share what i think i about it.thanks for review

Comment: Thanks. It worked absolutely fine..

Comment: @trojanfoe: Sorry for writing that "Single line". Actually I wanted a solution with "Minimal Lines"

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the subviews of your view as follows

```
for(UIView *v in yourView.subviews){
  if([v isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]){

  UILabel *label=(UILabel*)v
 // assign the required properties here.
```

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve the same thing before by subclassing `UILabel` and setting the needed properties in the constructor and just **change** the label class in the designer:

[image]

```
@implementation CustomLabel

//For Code initialized Labels
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code .. Set your properties here
      self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TradeGothicLTStd-Bold" size:self.font.pointSize];
    }
    return self;
}

//For designer initialized labels
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code .. Set your properties here
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TradeGothicLTStd-Bold" size:self.font.pointSize];
  }
  return self;
}
```